# Can I have multiple entry points using Rollup with Gulp?

Tags: gulp, rollupjs

I have a `gulpfile.js` that uses Rollup to build two distinct JS files (front-end and admin). The `rollup.config.js` method allows multiple entry points and bundles to be specified, but to achieve this with Gulp I've had to do a bit of a nasty workaround.

```
const javascripts = [
  {
    src: './app/assets/javascripts/main.js',
    dest: './public/javascripts/main.js',
    moduleName: 'main'
  },
  {
    src: './admin/assets/javascripts/admin.js',
    dest: './public/admin/javascripts/admin.js',
    moduleName: 'admin'
  }
]

gulp.task('js:compile', ()=> {
  javascripts.forEach((item)=> {
    return rollup({
      input: item.src,
      plugins: [
        builtins(),
        nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, browser: true }),
        commonjs({
          include: 'node_modules/**',
          exclude: 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-globals/**',
          ignoreGlobal: false,
          sourceMap: true,
          main: true,
          browser: true
        }),
        json(),
        buble()
      ]
    }).then(function (bundle) {
      return bundle.write({
        format: 'iife',
        name: item.moduleName,
        file: item.dest
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Is there a better way of achieving this? I'm not averse to reorganising my files to use globbing or something similar.

EDIT: I've updated it to use Node's `fs` rather than having to specify each script but this still feels a bit clunky to me.

```
gulp.task('js:compile', () => {
  fs.readdir('./app/assets/javascripts', (err, files) => {
    if(err) throw err

    files.forEach((file) => {
      if(!file.match('.js')) return false

      return rollup({
        input: `./app/assets/javascripts/${file}`,
        plugins: [
          builtins(),
          nodeResolve({ jsnext: true, browser: true }),
          commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            exclude: 'node_modules/rollup-plugin-node-globals/**',
            ignoreGlobal: false,
            sourceMap: true,
            main: true,
            browser: true
          }),
          json(),
          buble()
        ]
      }).then((bundle) => {
        return bundle.write({
          format: 'iife',
          name: file.split('.')[-2],
          file: `./public/javascripts/${file}`
        })
      }).catch( (e) => console.log(e) )
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I honestly don't understand why would the first solution you proposed is nasty? Obviously it would be better if rollup's gulp solution would be built in, but this is clean code easy to understand

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Now, you can just return an array of objects from `rollup.config.js`.

So if you

- need to compile a single file, return the object `export default {...}`
- need to **compile multiple files**, return list of objects `export default [{...},{...},{...}, ...]`

Look here for inspiration

- [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/rollup)

Comment: How would one watch multiple entry points this way with livereload and serve if only one port should be used and all files watched?

Answer (score 6):

You can now use https://github.com/alfredosalzillo/rollup-plugin-multi-input, it also preserve directory tree in output dir.

```
import multiInput from 'rollup-plugin-multi-input';

export default {
    input: ['src/**/*.js'],
    experimentalCodeSplitting: true,
    output: {
      format: 'esm',
      dir: 'dist'
    },
    plugins: [ multiInput() ],
};
```

Comment: this is not needed any more, you can just return list of objects for `export default [{..}, {...}]`

Comment: this is slower and using multiple configurations is not the same as exposing multiple input files. Also, you need to write the configuration for each file.

Comment: both could also compliment each other, say you have one bundle file and several worker files, use array of configs with 2 entries, 1 for bundle and 1 for all workers which will use multiInput plugin.